# Insert rows in dataframe with date, category and count

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe in R with 3 columns: a category (94 unique categories), a date column and an integer count column.  Example of the raw data:

```
id      date        count
4668    2017-01-01  1
4771    2017-01-01  8
4883    2017-01-01  2
4884    2017-01-01  6
```

I want to have  a row for every id for every day from 2017-01-01 till 2018-12-10 
 (708*94 =66.552 rows), right now I am missing rows for different clients. I tried using the following code to fill in the missing rows per id (count should be 0 for the missing rows):

```
> data_filled <- data%>%
+     mutate(Date = as.Date(date)) %>%
+     complete(Date = seq.Date(min(date), max(date), by="day"),id)
```

This filled some rows (with NA) but not all.
I also tried:

```
>data_filled <- data%>%
   +  complete(nesting(id, count), date = seq(min(date), max(date), by = "day"))
```

This gave me 1298888 rows.

I also tried to group/ungroup the dataframe but this did not work either. I'm a bit lost to what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Try with the `fill` argument

Comment: Is it because your `max(date)` is **NOT** `2018-12-10`, so you need to manually specify it...?

Comment: Based on what @Sotos points out, it looks like maybe the sample of data you posted here isn't actually representative of what you're working with, since the dates don't go very high. Can you post a larger sample that more accurately shows the issue? Using `dput` is very helpful, especially in dealing with data types like dates

Comment: The data is sorted by date, it the last date is 2018-12-10. There are more than 50000 rows so I couldnt post everything.